# Hyperledger explorer shows always as 1 node for fabric network on 3 virtual machines and peer status as down

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-explorer

I have Hyperledger fabric network running in 3 virtual machines and cluster management is being done using Docker Swarm. One virtual machine contains Orderer, CLI and Hyperledger explorer setup, whereas the other two machines are having 4 organisation configured each organisation having 1 CA, 2 peers and 1 CouchDB instance.

Hyperledger explorer always shows Node count as 1 and peer status being always down. Transactions, when placed, are properly propagated and they are reflected in charts as well.

Answer (score 0):

Peers are shown as down when the blockchain-explorer-container is not able to reach/ping them. You can test it with `docker exec -ti blockchain-explorer ping peer1.org1.example.com`. Replace `peer1.org1.example.com` with the peer-address you wrote in your config.json-file. If the result is something like `ping: bad address "peer1.org1.example.com"`, then the container can't ping it. You have two possibilities now. You can change in your config.json-file the peer-address to the ip-address:

```
"url": "grpcs://ip-address:7051",
"eventUrl": "grpcs://ip-address:7053"
```

or you can add the host within the docker run command. If you start the explorer with deploy-explorer.sh it is in the method deploy_run_explorer():

```
docker run \
        -d \
        --name $fabric_explorer_name \
        --net $docker_network_name --ip $explorer_ip \
        -e DATABASE_HOST=$db_ip \
        -e DATABASE_USERNAME=$explorer_db_user \
        -e DATABASE_PASSWD=$explorer_db_pwd \
        -v $network_config_file:/opt/explorer/app/platform/fabric/config.json \
        -v $network_crypto_base_path:/tmp/crypto \
        -p 8090:8080 \
        --add-host=peer1.org1.example.com:ip-address \           <-- New line
        --add-host=peer2.org2.example.com:ip-address \           <-- New line
        $fabric_explorer_tag
```